# How to fix row value in a table passed from controller using ajax?

Tags: laravel

I have to pass table value from controller to view using ajax. I am succeeded to pass table value but all the data comes in a same column. I want to show data in row.

I have tried possible cases. Since, this is the first time i am getting this problem, so i request to guide me.

//this is my table code in view:

```
 <table class="report">
    <tr>
   <th class="report-th"> Module ID </th>
   <th class="report-th"> Module Name </th>
   <th class="report-th"> Module Status </th>
</tr>
<tr id='values'>
</tr>
```

//this is my ajax:

```
 $(function () {
        $(".report").click(function () {
            var title = $(this).data('title');

            var id=$(this).data('id');
            $("#project-title").val(title);

             $('#project-id').val(id);


                $.ajax({


                    url: "{{url('tms/projects/',[null])}}/"+id,
                       method: 'GET',

                       success:function(response){
                     // console.log(response);
                       $('#values').html(response);
                 }
          });
        });

    });
```

//this is my controller:

```
    public function showajax($id){
       $modules= modules::where('project_id',$id)->get();

    foreach($modules as $row)
    {
        $html[]=
              '<td>' . $row->id . '</td>' .
                 '<td>' . $row->title . '</td>' .
                 '<td>' . $row->status. '</td>'.
                 '<br/>';
    }  

     return Response::json($html);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call function,

```
$(function () {
        $(".report").click(function () {
            var title = $(this).data('title');

            var id=$(this).data('id');
            $("#project-title").val(title);

             $('#project-id').val(id);


                $.ajax({


                    url: "{{url('tms/projects/',[null])}}/"+id,
                    //type instead of method
                    type: 'GET',

                       success:function(response){
                     // console.log(response);
                       // append instead of html
                       $('#values').append(response.html);
                 }
          });
        });

    });
```

Your Controller,

```
 public function showajax($id){
       $modules= modules::where('project_id',$id)->get();

    foreach($modules as $row)
    {
        $html[]=
              '<td>' . $row->id . '</td>' .
                 '<td>' . $row->title . '</td>' .
                 '<td>' . $row->status. '</td>'.
                 '<br/>';
    }  

     return Response::json(['success' => true, 'html'=>$html]);

}
```

Comment: thanks for your response sir, I tried it but same problem appeared. It was a simple code error , i just have solved it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to your response, Adding a class in the row doesn't solve your problem. You have to use [insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/)

```
var $tableRow = $('.report tr');

$.ajax({
    url: "{{url('tms/projects/',[null])}}/"+id,
    method: 'GET',
    success:function(response){
        $(response).insertAfter( $tableRow );
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for your response, bt after using ur suggestion , i am not getting any value. It is showing Uncaught ReferenceError: $tableRow is not defined as a error